# A Generalization of growth exponents

Tags: cv.complex-variables

The growth exponent of a function $f(\sigma + it)$ is defined as
the least nonnegative real number $\psi(\sigma)$ satisfying
$$
f(\sigma + it) \ll |t|^{\psi(\sigma) + \epsilon}
$$
as $t \to \infty$, for each $\epsilon > 0$. The symbol $\ll$ should be read as the usual big-oh notation.

If $f(s, a)$ is a function of two complex variables $s, a$ analytic in s and a, respectively, and $\psi_{a}(\sigma)$ is
defined as the least nonnegative real number satisfying
$$
f(\sigma + it, a) \ll |t|^{\psi_{a}(\sigma) + \epsilon}
$$
as $t \to \infty$, for each $\epsilon > 0$, then is there anything known about
the continuity/convexity in the variable a, for fixed $\sigma$, of the function $\psi_{a}(\sigma)$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is clearly not continuous, unless I am missing something. E.g. consider $f(s,a):= a\cdot s^2$, at $a=0$.

Comment: That's exactly right. Then, I tend to feel like asking if  $\psi_{a}(\sigma) = 0$ for all $a$ in some interval $(c, d)$ implies $f(s, a) = 0$ for all $a$ in $(c, d)$, or not. But this question might seem to be too general.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, $\psi_a(\sigma)$ clearly does not depend continuously on $a$; consider $f(s,a) := a\cdot s^2$ at $a=0$.

For the question in your comment, note that this cannot remotely be true, even for the growth exponent in one variable. Indeed, e.g. by Arakelian's approximation theorem we can construct entire functions that are bounded on some arbitrary collection of vertical strips, while having arbitrarily fast growth on some other collection of vertical lines.

Comment: My original question is resolved with Arakelian's approximation theorem; and yet, over the last several months, my interest has been in analyzing the growth exponent $\psi_{a}(\sigma)$ of integrals $\int_{0}^{1}f(\sigma + it, u)(u + a)^{-A}du$ with f being analytic in s and u in appropriate regions and growing at most polynomially in $t$ for each fixed $\sigma$, and A < 1. If you are generous enough, please give me your analysis on this problem too. Thanks. (I have been told of an example that for some nonanalytic f(s, u), $\psi_{a}(\sigma)$ could be made as big as one wish when $a = 0$.)

Comment: @Catman You might wish to post another question, giving all the details. (You could then post a link here if you wish.)